# Solving the equation $\int G(t) dt =\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I have to solve the equation 
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{f(t)}{1+(x-t)^2} dt =\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$
I tried change of variables to make the $\frac{1}{1+(x-t)^2}$ part resemble $e^{h(x)}$ so I can use the inverse Fourier transform. But I can't get it right.

Is it the right way to approach this problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is anything given about $\;f\;$? Continuous, derivable...? The part you want to make ressemble $\;e^{h}\;$ seems to me more like an arctangent...

Comment: You seem to have $\left(f\ast \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)(x)=\mathrm{sinc}(x)$. This does give you the fourier transform of $f$, assuming you have a reason to assume it exists (as per @DonAntonio's questions). Can you find the inverse transform?

Comment: @DonAntonio: no, no additional information has been given.

Comment: @JonathanY. I think I understand. Do you mean that I should apply Fourier transform to both sides of the convolution to get: $\hat{f} \cdot \widehat{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=\widehat{sinc (x)}$? Then I can calculate $\hat{f}$ and use inverse transform?

Comment: That's what I meant, but I thought that was your own suggestion originally.

Comment: @JonathanY.: No, originally I was thinking to do something else. But your way is better! I solved it and got $f(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi (1+x^2)} (1+e\cdot(i+x)\cdot \sin (x))$. Does it look anything like the answer? Tried to check with wolfram, but it couldn't compute the integral...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to leave this unanswered, so I will answer my own question.

Note that the left side is in fact a convolution:
$$\left( f \star \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\cdot \frac{1}{1+(x-t)^2} dt $$

Thus $\left( f \star \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and therefore $\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=\widehat{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$.

We know (standard calculation) that $\widehat{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}(\omega)=\pi \cdot e^{-|\omega|}$ and $\widehat{\frac{\sin x}{x}}(\omega)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \pi  & |\omega| \leq 1 \\
  0 & |\omega|>1
 \end{array}
\right.$

Therefore $\widehat{f}(\omega) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  e^{|\omega|}  &|\omega| \leq 1 \\
  0 & |\omega| > 1
 \end{array}
\right.$. Using inverse Fourier transform we get $$f(x)=\frac{-1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\left(1+e\cdot(i+x)\cdot \sin(x) \right) .$$